# Newtonsoft exception in Blazor .NET 6 only in Production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, blazor, production-environment

I need your help for a problem in PRODUCTION environment!

I'm building an .NET 6 Blazor WASM-Hosted application, which **works fine** in localhost.

However, in **production environment**, after publishing the solution, when I try to get some users, I encounter the below exception:

> A member with the name '' already exists on
> 'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[einvoices.Shared.Models.UserEntity],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[einvoices.Shared.Models.UserRoleEntity]]'.
> Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

This is a front-end exception, coming from the **Newtonsoft** nuget package.

I have a GetUsers() method in my Services in the front-end, which I call:

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<UserEntity>,List<UserRoleEntity>>> GetUsers()
{
   return await _httpService.Get<Tuple<List<UserEntity>, List<UserRoleEntity>>>($"{url}/GetUsers");
}
```

I also have in the front-end a HttpService to organize all my GET-POST-PUT-DELETE calls:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

    _loadingService.Show();
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    _loadingService.Hide();

    string responseString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        T? responseDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
        return responseDeserialized;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(responseString);
    }
}
```

Now, if I use the System.Text.Json package instead of Newtonsoft, I get the below exception:

> ConstructorParamIncompleteBinding,
> System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HAFeInvoices.Shared.Models.UserEntity],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HAFeInvoices.Shared.Models.UserRoleEntity]]

I have ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.27 Hosting Bundle installed in the server.
All my application packages have been updated to 6.0.27 version.

It is worth-mentioning that the error says

> A member with the name '' already exists ...

and the name is empty. Usually a specific member name had to appear.

As you can see, I am using Tuples, if this means anything.

Do you have any idea what is going on?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show the definition of your UserEntity and UserRoleEntity. 
Intead of returning a Tuple I would consider making an object to wrap those two lists instead. then you can control the deserialization of your object instead of the built in Tuple